# Login loop moved /home/ to new HDD now Xauthority issue

Tags: 18.04

I did a fresh install today. Os on ssd then moved my `/home/` to the new setup HDD. I restarted the pc and got the login loop. Id enter credentials then,blank screen, then have to log in again. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to terminal. Login in through there. `startx` gave me an Xauthority error. I checked the `/home/` file available to me and there is nothing in it. I was trying to get to /home/user/ to change or check `.Xauth` file but nothing is there. I also tried a `sudo chown sp:sp` --a couple diff ones.

I am planning on just doing another fresh install tomorrow. If it would just be easier? However if it is easier as I have no data on the drives, how do I prevent this from happening again when I change my `/home/` to the bigger HDD again? I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: A GUI/desktop login requires access to your $HOME directory (/home/$USER/) to create temporary work files.  It reads like to me, it cannot access that directory (it needs not only access, but writable access) to create the necessary files. If that isn't located; your GUI login will fail & you're logged out (no message).  I'd suspect this is your issue, not .Xauth, though the effect is the same.  I suspect you didn't correctly reflect changes for your new setup in your /etc/fstab (file system table)

Comment: Ok so i believe you are correct. I did a fresh install again today. Thought I added 8t correctly this time but i am still on the login loop.

Comment: When i make the initial move of files before I delete what should be now copied home files it does give me alot of errors on that. Im just not sure where i am going qrong. An i cant use my pc until i get this working. I have lots of work to do! Haha

Comment: I just `cp -pr` (or `rsync` but usually `cp`) my files from one device to another; then make changes to `fstab` later; this later step must reflect the changes made; is not part of the copy step - but tells your OS to look on the new drive/new location for files, and not the old drive/location. How you copy files is up to you; I'd ensure you preserve (-p) filebits otherwise you'll have issues on certain files (only a few). You've been vague with no details (I don't know what you mean by *8t*); encryption complicates things only slightly, a change in *fs* type however can create issues.